# Summing multidimensional NumPy arrays with unexpected results?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am a bit confused as to what is going on here when summing multidimensional arrays.

I cannot recreate the problem with a minimum working example, even though the operations are the same, but here is the code:

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
y = np.linspace(0,10,10)
t = np.linspace(0,10,5)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

foo = np.zeros((5,10,10,10))
for i in range(5):
  foo[i] = t[i]*np.sin(xx*yy*np.pi)
```

So, I have a function that is applied across a meshgrid for each trace (t). I then want to stack each trace and plot the resulting image like so:

```
bar = np.sum(foo, 0)
plt.imshow(bar[:,:,5])
```

However, this produces the wrong image. But this operation -- which I believed to be equivalent, produces the correct image.

```
foobar = foo[0,:,:,5] + foo[1,:,:,5] + foo[2,:,:,5] + foo[3,:,:,5] + foo[4,:,:,5]
plt.imshow(foobar)
```

And with my minimum working example provided above, it does what I expect. Great! However, applying this to my actual data does not result in the same image, and this is confusing the absolute dog poop out of me. So if someone could help explain what is happening here.

```
## . . Define parameters
ng    = 20       # Number of geophones
nVp   = 200      # Number of Vp test points
nfreq = 200      # Number of frequency test points
ndata = 600      # Number of data points per trace
dt    = 1/16000  # Time_Delta

## . . Define gridspace
freq = np.linspace(0, 40, nfreq)  # Frequency spectrum (Hz)    
Vp   = np.linspace(1, 100, nVp)   # Phase velocity spectrum (m/s)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(freq, Vp)

## . . Setup gridspace for the slant stack function
S = np.zeros((ng, nfreq, nVp, ndata), dtype=complex)

## . . Calculate dispersion with varying phase velocity and frequency
for idx, trace in enumerate(seismic_gather[0].trace):
  ## Get the fourier transformation and normalization of the waveform
  U = np.fft.fft(trace.data)  # Fourier transform 
  N = U/np.abs(U)             # Normalize waveform

  ## Apply dynamic linear moveout
  P = 2*np.pi*X*trace.offset/Y             # Dispersion property
  S[idx] = np.exp(1j*P)[:,:,np.newaxis]*N

## . . Unexpected results
foo = np.sum(S, 0)
# plt.imshow(foo[:,:,50])

## . . Expected results
bar = S[0,:,:,50]
for i in range(1,20):
  bar += S[i,:,:,50]
# plt.imshow(bar)
```

Image with unexpected results:
[image]

Image with expected results:
[image]

What is the difference between the two methods? Why does it appear to work on my minimal working example, but not beyond this?

Comment: `bar = S[0,:,:,50]` is going to be a view of S, so you are modifying S, and you are trying to plot a complex image ...

Comment: `t[i]*np.sin(xx*yy*np.pi)` is a (10,10) array.  Assigned to `foo[i]` this will put identical values in axis 1.   That is  `foo[1,:,1,1]` is a 1d array of 10 identical values.  Do you want that.  You could skip the loop with: `t[:,None,None]*np.sin(xx*yy*np.pi)` though this is still a  (5,10,10) array.

Comment: `np.allclose(bar[:,:,5], foobar)` is True in my testing.